# invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript error in C?

Tags: c, matrix, compiler-errors

I am trying segment my matrix 2by2 square matrices. but I'm getting a compilation fault and don't know why. My code:

```
    int main()
    {
        int rowsize,n,i,j,l,k, var=0,var2=0,count = 0,square2by2[2][2];
        printf("Size of square matrix: " );
        scanf("%d",&n);
        rowsize=n;
        int *matrix = (int *)malloc(rowsize * rowsize * sizeof(int));
        for (i = 0; i <  rowsize; i++)
          for (j = 0; j < rowsize; j++)
             *(matrix + i*rowsize + j) = ++count;

        for (i = 0; i <  rowsize; i++)
         {
            for (j = 0; j < rowsize; j++)
            {
                printf("%d ", *(matrix + i*rowsize + j));
            }
            printf("\n");
         }
         for( i=0, l=var2 ;i<2 , l<var2+rowsize ;i++,l++)
        {
            for( j=0 , k=var ; j<2, k<var+2 ;j++,k++)
            {
                square2by2[i][j]=matrix[l][k]; // error line
            }

            if(i==1)
            {
                var++;
                if(var==rowsize-1) 
                {
                    printf("\n");
                    for(int x=0;x<2;x++)
                    {
                        printf("\n");
                        for(int y=0;y<2;y++)
                        {
                            printf("%d\t",square2by2[x][y]);
                        }
                    }
                    var = 0;
                    i-=2;
                    l-=1;
                    if(l==rowsize+1) 
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    i-=2;
                    l-=2;
                    printf("\n");
                    for(int x=0;x<2;x++)
                    {
                        printf("\n");
                        for(int y=0;y<2;y++)
                        {
                            printf("%d\t",square2by2[x][y]);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
return 0;
        }
```

and the error is

> 37    36  [Error] invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
>   why am i getting this error?

Comment: Did you try to ... Google it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ error: invalid types int int for array subscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165449/c-error-invalid-types-int-int-for-array-subscript)

Comment: i did try already but i couldn't solve problem

Comment: is that really a duplicate? the accepted answer draws a line between C++ and c. But it won't hurt to look into the three answers over there, @pseudocode - maybe one of them can help you in spite of it being a C++ question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matrix has been declared as int* but is being used as int[][]

To fix, use

```
square2by2[i][j]=matrix[l * rowsize + k];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your declaration for `matrix`:

```
int *matrix = ...
```

This declares `matrix` to be a pointer to an `int`, or equivalently a pointer into a one-dimensional `int` array.  The expression `matrix[l]` is therefore `int`-valued.  You cannot apply the second `[k]` index to an `int`.

To do what you're trying to do, you need a pointer into a two-dimensional array.  Here's how you can do that:

```
int a[dim1][dim2];
int (*p)[dim2] = a;    // The parentheses are necessary!
```

Here `p` is a pointer into `a`, so you can reference `p` just as you would `a`, e.g. `p[i][j]`.