# Invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript error

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, subscript

I'm migrating into C++ from Java world and am trying to port over an example. I'm getting an error in that I'm not accessing my arrays correctly. I tried pointing to them, using -> and * notation but I'm having a hard time getting my head around it. I believe it's the same basic error repeated multiple times. I've highlighted the three areas where the errors begin, excluding the multiples of the same error. Any help would go a long way in my understanding of the topic. Thanks!

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::setup(){
    colorCount = 20;
    int *hueValues = new int[colorCount];
    int *saturationValues = new int[colorCount];
    int *brightnessValues = new int[colorCount];

ofColor::fromHsb(360, 100, 100, 100);
ofFill();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::update(){

}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::draw(){
    // ------ colors ------
    // create palette
    for (int i=0; i<colorCount; i++) {
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            hueValues[i] = (int) random(0,360);                  // invalid types 'int[int]' fr array subscript
            saturationValues[i] = 100;  
            brightnessValues[i] = (int) random(0,100);
        } 
        else {
            hueValues[i] = 195;
            saturationValues[i] = (int) random(0,100);
            brightnessValues[i] = 100;
        }
    }

    // ------ area tiling ------
    // count tiles
    int counter = 0;
    // row count and row height
    int rowCount = (int)random(5,40);                  // At this point in file
    float rowHeight = (float)ofGetHeight()/(float)rowCount;

    for(int i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
        // seperate each line in parts  
        // how many fragments
        int partCount = i+1;
        parts = new float[0];                  // Cannot convert "float" to "float" in assignment

        for(int ii=0; ii<partCount; ii++) {
            // sub fragments or not?
            if (random(1.0) < 0.075) {
                // take care of big values      
                int fragments = (int)random(2,20);
                partCount = partCount + fragments; 
                for(int iii=0; iii<fragments; iii++) {
                    parts = append(parts, random(2));
                }              
            }  
            else {
                parts = append(parts, random(2,20));   
            }
        }

        // add all subparts
        float sumPartsTotal = 0;
        for(int ii=0; ii<partCount; ii++) sumPartsTotal += parts[ii];

        // draw rects
        float sumPartsNow = 0;
        for(int ii=0; ii<parts.length; ii++) {
            // get component color values
            int index = counter % colorCount;
            fill(hueValues[index],saturationValues[index],brightnessValues[index]);

            sumPartsNow += parts[ii];
            rect(map(sumPartsNow, 0,sumPartsTotal, 0,width),rowHeight*i, 
                 map(parts[ii], 0,sumPartsTotal, 0,width)*-1,rowHeight);

            counter++;
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: `int *hueValues = new int[colorCount];` - this declares a variable local to the `testApp::setup` function. Maybe you accidentally declared your member variables as `int`?

Comment: Please stop using `new[]` and switch to a standard container like `std::vector`.

Comment: Right, like I said I'm moving into C++ from Java. new[] is standard notation for Java. I will try that and see if it helps.

Comment: Use `std::vector` for dynamically signed arrays. Raw pointers to dynamically allocated objects usually lead to trouble.

Comment: Ok, I would like to adopt the best coding practices. How can I implement the `std::vector` into my code?

Comment: [c++ - invalid types 'int\[int\]' for array subscript - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/363864/5267751) -- but this question doesn't have a [example].

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're allocating space for the arrays in the `setup()` function, but your pointers are defined locally and as such go out of scope as soon as the function has finished execution; when you try and reference them in the `draw()` function you're getting a compiler error because the symbols aren't found/aren't defined correctly. Move the `int *hueValues/saturationValues/brightnessValues` declarations into the private section of the `testAPP` header file, keep the allocation code (`new int[coloCount]`) in the setup function, and then you should be able to reference the arrays in the `draw()` function without an error.

testApp.h:

```
private:
int* hueValues;
int* saturationValues;
int* brightnessValues;
```

testApp.cpp

```
void testApp::setup(){
  hueValues = new int[colorCount];
  ...
}
```

Comment: That seemed to remove the errors from my setup() function, but now the errors in draw() simply say: "At this point in file" and don't give me much information for debugging. They systematically seem to appear whenever I try to assign a random value to the the array I've initialized. For instance, at: `hueValues[i] = (int) random(0,360);`

Comment: Where is random defined? Can you provide the full compilation error?