# invalid types for array subscripts

Tags: c++, arrays

I am getting several errors for array subscripts and also no matching function for call to get line... Im not sure exactly why.

error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript

error: invalid types ‘double[int]’ for array subscript

error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript

error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(bool)’

here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct CountiesFirst
{
   int counties;
   double poverty_rate;
   double income;
};

const int MAX_COUNTIES = 10;

bool openFile(ifstream& input)
{
  int counties;
  double poverty_rate;
  double income;
  int i=0;
  char filename[256];

  cout << "Welcome to the Appalachian Poverty/Income Report\n";
  cout << "Enter input file name: ";
  cin >> filename;

  input.open(filename);
  getline(input, counties);

  while (getline(!input.eof() && i < MAX_COUNTIES))
  {
     input>>counties[i];
     input>> poverty_rate[i] >> income[i];
     ++i;
  }
  while (input.eof())
  {
     input.putback (i) ;
     cout << "Input file is empty" << endl;
     return i;
  }

  return !input.fail();
  }

  void printTable(string counties[],
      double poverty_rate[],
      double income[],
      size_t size)
  {
  cout << "Counties     Poverty Rate        Salary\n";
  cout << "---------------------------------------\n";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
    cout.width(17);
    cout << left << counties[i];
    cout << poverty_rate[i] << "%";
    cout.width(13);
    cout << right << "$" << income[i] << endl;
  }
}


  int main()
  {
    CountiesFirst counties [MAX_COUNTIES];
    int filename;

    ifstream input;
    ofstream output;

    if (openFile(input))
   {
  //sort(counties,  poverty_rate, income, size);
  void printTable(string counties[], double poverty_rate[],  double income[],       int size);
  }
  else
  {
     cout << "Input file does not exist.\n";
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

     input.close();
     output.close();
   }
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `getline(!input.eof() && i < MAX_COUNTIES)` This is not how you use this function. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: `cin >> filename;` This is dangerous. What if the user enters more than 255 characters? Use `std::string`

Comment: Seems that your code have endless problems. If I were you, I'd rewrite the code from the beginning.

Comment: Almost duplicate of [c++ - invalid types 'int\[int\]' for array subscript - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/363864/5267751) -- except that in this case the dimension is 0->1 instead of 3->4.

Answer (score 0):

1. Here:

   ```
   int counties;
   double poverty_rate;   

   input >> counties[i];
   input >> poverty_rate[i] >> income[i];
   ```

   You are trying to work with `int` and `double` like they are arrays. They are not.
   It produces "invalid types for array subscript" error.
2. [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) takes `istream` and `string` as arguments.

   At the same time, here you are passing `int`:

   ```
   int counties;
   getline(input, counties);
   ```

   Here you are doing something completely wrong:

   ```
   getline(!input.eof() && i < MAX_COUNTIES)
   ```

   It produces "no matching function" error.