# C++ question regarding multidimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays

My C++ skills are rusty but trying to help my son with his assignment so pardon me if its very simple.

I am trying to find all of the neighbors of an element in array and seeing if that particular element is larger than all of its neighbors.

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int row2(int arr[][3], int n){
  cout << "row2";
    if (arr[1][n] > arr[0][n] && arr[1][n] > arr[0][1] && arr[1][n] > arr[1][1] && arr[1][n] > arr[2][1] && arr[1][n] > arr[2][n]){
      return true;
    }
    else 
      return false;


}
int row3(int arr[][3], int n){
  cout << "row3==n";
  cout << n;
  if (n == 0 || n == 2){
    
    if (arr[3][n] > arr[1][n] && arr[3][n] > arr[3][1] && arr[3][n] > arr[1][1]){
      cout << "row3 if";
      return true;
    }
    else 
     cout << "row3 else";
      return false;
  }
  else{
    if (arr[3][1] > arr[3][2] && arr[3][1] > arr[3][0] && arr[3][1] > arr[1][2] && arr[3][1] > arr[1][0] && arr[3][1] > arr[1][1]){
      return true;
    }
    else 
      return false;

  }
}
```

When compiling I get an error in this line val = arr[counterx] [counter];  expected body of lambda expression
val4 = arr[val2], [val3];

Any pointers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You sure `arr` is a multidimensional array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [invalid types 'int\[int\]' for array subscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363864/invalid-types-intint-for-array-subscript)

Comment: That having said, you're probably using a different compiler or compiler version.

Comment: @J, I have edited the code. ** is not part of the code.

Comment: What is `val4 = arr[val2], [val3];` supposed to do? Did you mean to write `arr[val2][val3];`?

Comment: @PaulRooney I tried that, but it gave the error the subscripted value is not an array, poinet, or vector.

Answer (score 0):

> expected body of lambda expression val4 = arr[val2], [val3];

Seems like a syntax error on this line `val4 = arr[val2], [val3];` and not the one you mentioned in the question.

I assume you meant to write `val4 = arr[val2][val3];` without the comma.

That being said, the values of val2 and val3 are being assigned the same value and may cause an index out of bounds exception if unchecked. Moreover, starting counter and counterx at -1 will cause out of bounds exceptions.

Moreover, you cannot pass a multidimensional array to a function without passing it as a double pointer or hardcoding the size.

---

EDIT 1:
I put together a solution for finding the max number in each row. It's not the most optimized code but it's quick and works. I assumed the row,col sizes could change, so I'm using std::vector instead of std:array or primitive array. However, you could revert back if you know you can hardcode int[3][3] into your solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
 
void findit(std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr){  
  for (size_t rowsIndex = 0; rowsIndex <= arr.size(); rowsIndex++){
    std::vector<int> row = arr[rowsIndex];
    int maxNum = *std::max_element(row.begin(), row.end());

    std::cout<< "largest num in row " << rowsIndex << ": " << maxNum << std::endl;
  }
}

int main(){
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr;
  arr.push_back({0, 1, 2 });
  arr.push_back({4, 5, 6 });
  arr.push_back({8, 9, 10});
  
  findit(arr);
}
```

---

EDIT 2:

If you want to check a target index against adjacent indecies, there's no need to use a forloop. There are only 4 (or 8) possible indecies to check against, just easier (and efficient) to hardcode them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

void checkIfIndexIsLargestInItsAdjacency(std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr, size_t targetRow, size_t targetColumn){
    int targetNumber = arr[targetRow][targetColumn];
    int numberToTheLeft = targetColumn > 0 ? arr[targetRow][targetColumn-1] : 0;
    int numberToTheRight = targetColumn + 1 < arr[targetRow].size() ? arr[targetRow][targetColumn+1] : 0;
    int numberToTheUp = targetRow > 0 ? arr[targetRow-1][targetColumn] : 0;
    int numberToTheDown = targetRow + 1 < arr.size() ? arr[targetRow+1][targetColumn] : 0;
    std::cout<< "targetNumber: " << targetNumber << std::endl;
    std::cout<< "Number to the left: " << numberToTheLeft << std::endl;
    std::cout<< "Number to the right: " << numberToTheRight << std::endl;
    std::cout<< "Number to the up: " << numberToTheUp << std::endl;
    std::cout<< "Number to the down: " << numberToTheDown << std::endl;
    
    std::array<int, 4> adjacentNumbers = {numberToTheLeft, numberToTheRight, numberToTheUp, numberToTheDown};
    int maxAdjacentNum = *std::max_element(adjacentNumbers.begin(), adjacentNumbers.end());
    
    std::cout << "Target number is " << (maxAdjacentNum >= targetNumber? "smaller" : "bigger") << " than adjacent numbers" << std::endl;
}

int main(){
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr;
  arr.push_back({0, 1, 2 });
  arr.push_back({4, 5, 6 });
  arr.push_back({8, 9, 10});
  
  checkIfIndexIsLargestInItsAdjacency(arr, 1, 1);
  checkIfIndexIsLargestInItsAdjacency(arr, 2, 2);
}
```

Example output:

```
targetNumber: 5
Number to the left: 4
Number to the right: 6
Number to the up: 1
Number to the down: 9
Target number is smaller than adjacent numbers
targetNumber: 10
Number to the left: 9
Number to the right: 0
Number to the up: 6
Number to the down: 0
Target number is bigger than adjacent numbers
```

Comment: You could also use a forloop to grab the values of `{numberToTheLeft, numberToTheRight, ...}` instead of having four separate variables, whichever is easier.

Comment: Thanks before trying your code I  have modified the posted code to below but its not printing any value

Answer (score 0):

The shown code has several bugs, and errors. Both syntax errors and logical errors.

```
void findit(int arr[], int sizey, int sizex)
```

This declares the first parameter to be a plain, garden variety array. Just a one dimensional array. Typical values in this array, that you might found would be `arr[0]`, or `arr[1]`, or maybe `arr[x]` if `x` was some integer variable. But then, in the this function:

```
 val = arr[counterx] [counter];
```

this tries to access `arr` as if it was a two-dimensional array, instead: `arr[something][somethingelse]`. That would be a two-dimensional array, while the `arr` is declared as a one-dimensional array.

In your `main` you declare a

```
  int arr[3][3]
```

which is a two-dimensional array, but then pass it to `findit`:

```
   findit(arr, m,n);
```

However, as we've just discovered, the first parameter to `findit` is not a two-dimensional array, but a one dimensional array. It's clear that `findit`'s `arr` should be declared as a two-dimensional array.

However there is no way, in C++, to pass a two-dimensional array to a C++ function, with unspecified first ***and*** second dimension. C++ does not work this way. In an array parameter specification, in C++, only the ***first*** array dimnension can be left unspecified. The 2nd, and ***all*** following dimensions must be specified. You could, for example, declare:

```
 void findit(int arr[][3], int sizey, int sizex)
```

That would allow you to pass any two-dimensional array of `int`s, as long as the 2nd dimension is 3. But then passing both `size` parameters is meaningless. It is only necessary to explicitly pass in the size of the first dimension, since the size of the second dimension is already known.

Finally:

```
 val4 = arr[val2], [val3];
```

It is unclear what this is, but this is not a valid C++ syntax. If you meant to access an element in this two-dimensional array, using the given indices, the appropriate syntax would be:

```
 val4 = arr[val2][val3];
```

This addresses the fundamental compilation errors in the shown code. Unfortunately there are many, many obvious logical problems in the shown code. For example, one of the logical problems:

```
 val = arr[counterx] [counter];
```

If you inspect the preceding `for` loops, you will discover that:

```
 for (int counterx = -1; counter <= sizex; counter++){
```

So, the `counterx` variable will start iterating from -1, so the above will appear to try to evaluate:

```
 val = arr[-1][counter];
```

In C++, no array has a value at a negative index offset, so the above logic will result in undefined behavior, and nonsensical results. If you have any kind of an array, like `x[]`, you might find something at `x[0]`, and at `x[1]`, but not at `x[-1]`. The same applies to multi-dimensional arrays too.

This is the first logical error that was obvious to the naked eye, and there are probably a few more, here. Overall, the approach in the shown code is somewhat unclear. You might benefit from taking a step back, and redesigning the overall approach for this task, since the shown logic does not appear to be going about it correctly, in several fundamental ways.

Comment: I changed the syntax errors and the -1 error, but it seems the output is just a bunch of random letters, and quite a bit of them. Are there any other ways this code be changed that you see? Thanks!

Comment: The described goal: find values in a matrix that are larger than all of its neighbors, has two necessary logical components: 1) scanning each value in the matrix 2) comparing each value to all of its neighbors. It goes without saying, that values on the matrix' edges won't have every neighbor that values in the middle of the matrix. The ones in middle have 9 neighboring values. Values in the corners, for example, have only 3. Therefore, this logic must have some means of determining which neighbors of each value actually exist. This kind of logic is completely missing from the shown code.

Comment: Next: once you figured out which neighbors each value has, it's obvious that you have to check them one at a time, and if you find any one that's larger, you're done, his value does not qualify, no longer necessary to check the remaining neghbors, your goose is cooked. This kind of decision making is completely missing from the shown code.

Comment: Thanks so much Sam for your response. Will try fixing the code and come back.

Comment: Changed the  code little bit but no output is printed

Comment: Works just fine for me, after the missing `#include <vector>`.